# Rails dynamic collection name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to specify a dynamic collection name in rails, for example:

`a = House.last.#{ dynamic collection name here }`

i.e: `House.last.cars`, `House.last.people`, etc

Ideally, i'd be able to use ActiveSupport's inflectors, like:

`a = House.last."cars".pluralize.constantize`

or const_get

`House.last.Object.const_get("cars".pluralize)`

or something like that but obviously that's not the usecase for those methods. I was thinking of defining a class method and just mapping the strings to constants, but before that, is there a 'one liner' way of achieving this?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? `House.last.send("cars")`

Comment: How are you planning to store the related objects in the database? Or *are* they database records?

Comment: `send` will work, but take care not to accept arbitrary method names (like "destroy")

Comment: @Vimsha wow, that's exactly it. I looked around for quite a while and didn't see this solution! Thanks and feel free to post it to the answers.

Comment: @zetetic yeah thanks, I will add some validations